# What goes on underneath error redirection?

Tags: redirect

While reading about linux I got the following:

> Because stderr is not the same as stdout, error messages will still be
>   seen on the terminal windows in the above example.
>
> If you want to redirect stderr to a separate file, you use stderr’s
>   file descriptor number (2), the greater-than sign (>), followed by the
>   name of the file you want to hold everything the running command
>   writes to stderr:
>
> ```
> $ do_something 2> error-file
> ```
>
> A special shorthand notation can be used to put anything written to
>   file descriptor 2 (stderr) in the same place as file descriptor 1
>   (stdout): 2>&1
>
> ```
> $ do_something > all-output-file 2>&1
> ```
>
> bash permits an easier syntax for the above:
>
> ```
> $ do_something >& all-output-file
> ```

Here `do_something` is some command. I am really not getting what is happening underneath in all 3 commands stated above. I know `&` is used for making a process a background process, but I am not getting the logic. I am new to this flavor please Can someone explain this?

Comment: Check [this stack overflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3385201/198224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion may be because `>&` is totally a different thing than `&`.

`>&` or `<&` are used in redirection to point at a file descriptor (fd).  The above cases redirect to 1 and 2, which are stdout and stderr respectively.

`>` means "redirect stdout"

`2>` means "redirect fd 2 (stderr)"

`>&2` means "redirect stdout to fd 2 (stderr)".  Note how this differs from `>2` which would mean "redirect stdout to a file named `2`" -- this is why the `&` is important.  It indicates that the next thing will be an fd, not a filename.

Now of course as you noted, if a `&` is sitting by itself without a redirection symbol, then it means something completely different -- "return immediately, run the preceding command in the background."